# Is the movie title "love and other drugs" a play on some phrase?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, puns

Does anyone know if the movie title "love and other drugs" is a play on some other phrase of the form *X and other Y*?

Comment: I would assume it's using a straight-forward analogy/metaphor between love and drugs.  Keep in mind that (illicit) drugs are often used as a substitute for the love that someone cannot seem to obtain.

Comment: Other recent movies: Love and other disasters; Love and other cults; Love and other catastrophes.

Comment: 1970: Lovers and Other Strangers.

Comment: If you're interested specifically in other titles, this would be better asked on another StackExchange (literature or film and TV). You can find a lot of poetry collections called things like *Love, and other poems* (by William Baxter, 1843) or *Love-and Other Things. A little book of verses.* By A. B. K. W.  (Cambridge : W. Heffer & Sons ; London : Simpkin, Marshall & Co, 1913.), and there's other "and other" things like Gerald Durrell's *My Family and Other Animals* (1956)

Comment: Thanks! The title rabbit hole is fun! But as is clearly indicated I am looking for an expression or phrase of the form X and other Y, to rule them all. Perhaps with the added constraint that X and Y are only metaphorically related, if it all.